# I want to run software on a GPU in a cluster. Does the software have to be on my machine or on the cluster?

Tags: linux, windows-10, gpu, cluster

My laptop runs Linux. If I need to run any (deep learning) code on a GPU, I do so on a university cluster that I have access to (which also runs Linux).

I want to use a piece of [commercially available software](https://topazlabs.com/video-enhance-ai/) that requires Windows 10 and (ideally) a GPU.

If I want to download and run this software, does that mean that I can:

(a) Download it to a local machine with Windows 10 and run the processing through the university GPU cluster

or

(b) I have to have the software and Windows 10 installed on the GPU cluster that I have access to. I am not the system admin and so would not be able to do this.

Or I am misunderstanding completely?

Comment: At first glance that looks like software that runs in an enclosed system (or can submit the job to a cloud service). It doesn't look like you can utilise the cluster with it.

Comment: So it seems like my only option is to run it on a Windows 10 machine that has a GPU?